# Javascript Close Popup windows after certain time

Tags: javascript

Hi first of all I don't know JavaScript.  So I've got a popup window on my main page with Christmas wishes for the clients.  I want the popup windows to close after say 20 seconds.  I got the following code from the internet, the popup window opens fine but I need help with the following:

1. Where do I put in the time limit for the popup window and
2. Where do I tell the page to run the function to close the popup window, I've got the funcion winClose but must I also put that in the  tag?:

**The code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function poponload()
{
    testwindow = window.open("cm.html", "myWindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=500");
}
function winClose() {
     myWindow.close()
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: poponload()" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function in `Javascript`, Usage :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(testwindow  && !testwindow.closed){
        self.setInterval("winClose()",20000);
    }
});
```

Comment: This would go in script tag. Normally I would put this at the bottom of the page. You will also have to include jquery in you scripts for this to work

Comment: yep, this goes inside your `script` tag and if you are using jquery addd a script link to jquery file or else just use `self.setInterval("winClose()",20000);` in `script` tag

Comment: Just a note for future viewers.  Don't pass strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval`.  Pass a function.  `self.setInterval(winClose, 20000);`