# Close Pop Up Message after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have this code which is a pop up message. On this specific code how could I close the pop up after 5 seconds?

```
function popUp(URL) {
    day = new Date();
    id = day.getTime();
    eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=550,height=420,left = 580,top = 335');");
}
```

Comment: Use the link to get your answer - it is a different question but it is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353126/javascript-close-popup-windows-after-certain-time

Comment: Please do not use `eval`!  Instead use an object.  `var pages = {};`  Then: `pages[id] = window.open();`.

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but -- I highly recommend you learn about, and beginning using, local variables (declared with the `var` keyword).

Comment: my problem is that all this code works normally on the site so please if I have to do any changes show me on this code. Or what I have to add.